# Ansible replace block of text in a specific file

Tags: ansible

I would like to force replace block of text from "global" to "/global" in a specific file.

For example:
From:

```
SOME DATA...
SOME DATA...
SOME DATA...
<global>
 <white_list>127.0.0.1</white_list>
 <white_list>::1</white_list>
 <white_list>^localhost.localdomain$</white_list>
</global>
SOME DATA...
SOME DATA...
SOME DATA...
```

To:

```
SOME DATA...
SOME DATA...
SOME DATA...
<global>
 <white_list>127.0.0.1</white_list>
 <white_list>::1</white_list>
 <white_list>^localhost.localdomain$</white_list>
 <white_list>{{ white_root_vpn }}</white_list>
 <white_list>{{ white_static1 }}</white_list>
</global>
SOME DATA...
SOME DATA...
SOME DATA...
```

Have you got any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [blockinfile module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/blockinfile_module.html).

> This module will insert/update/remove a block of multi-line text surrounded by customizable marker lines.

You would use it like:

```
- blockinfile:
    path: /path/to/file
    marker: "{mark}"
    marker_begin: "<global>"
    marker_end: "</global>"
    block: |-
      <white_list>127.0.0.1</white_list>
      <white_list>::1</white_list>
      <white_list>^localhost.localdomain$</white_list>
      <white_list>{{ white_root_vpn }}</white_list>
      <white_list>{{ white_static1 }}</white_list>
    state: present
```